# Tooltip for multiple data sets in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, scatter-plot

I have made a scatter plot by merging two individual scatter plots with data sets [x,y1] and [x,y2] (two values of y for one value of x). And I want to create tooltips for all the points depicting their x and y coordinates .So  tooltips depicting any point with coordinates (x,y1) should have the value of x and y1 and tooltips with coordinates x and y2 should show (x,y2) .Is there any way to create such a tooltip?

P.S :-  The chart also has overlapping points.

Comment: Could you give a brief sample of how your data looks, ideally with a [mcve] showing what you're doing currently?

Answer (score -2):

Use 'title' in the x or y..

For Ex: {x=value; title='Title Name'}